# Selenium doesn't open Chrome with automated software when I try to use a Chrome Profile

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to test Google one tap automatically, and so I need to be signed into a profile. I'm able to start a Chrome window with that specific profile; however, it's not being controlled by the driver. Is my issue with the 4th line? I tried a bunch of different ways to call the chrome driver but I can't seem to get it. When I use it normally without the options above, chrome starts with the correct Selenium driver.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(r"--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Taming\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
options.add_argument(r'--profile-directory=Profile 2')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\\Web Development\\Selenium Automated Test\\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
```

I get this error:

```
D:\Web Development\Selenium Automated Tests\login.py:31: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\\Web Development\\Selenium Automated Test\\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
Opening in existing browser session.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Web Development\Selenium Automated Tests\login.py", line 31, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\\Web Development\\Selenium Automated Test\\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Taming\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 84, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Taming\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 104, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Taming\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 286, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\Taming\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 378, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Taming\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Taming\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```